# jQuery UI does not work in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the jQuery UI library in my project. I have downloaded a jquery-ui-1.10.2.zip.

Then I've extracted files inside, copied and pasted .js and css files into corresponding packages(Contents, Scripts). Then I've added these lines in Bundle.Config.cs:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js",
                     "~/Scripts/jquery.ui.dialog.js"));
```

and so on. Then I've rendered in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

But it does not work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you include the regular jQuery library as well? Also, please be more specific than 'it does not work' - what did you try and what doesn't work?

Comment: Yes when I created the project, jquery library was already included there. I just tried to  test wether it works or not. I just put like this: $(document).ready(function(){ $("#divid").dialog() });, but dialog doesn't appear

Comment: Did you include the jquery ui stylesheet? Do you get a javascript error?

Answer (score 0):

I did everything perfect. I've got no error while running, but after running the project on browser, I had a look at the compiled source code of the page, then I understood that path to the script is Scripts/jquery-ui.js, but my page is located ar View/Home/ while scripts are located at Scripts/ folder. Then I just, changed the path to proper one. That's all:=)